# UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

this is my static_pages_controller_test,

```
    require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Error:

> StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE
>   constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at",
>   "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-17 05:49:27.300065', '2018-01-17
>   05:49:27.300065', 298486374)

and i have change user.yml as,

```
one:
email: test1@test.com

two:
email: test2@test.com
```

Error:

> StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: fixture key is not a hash:
>   C:/Sites/IntenetChatSystem/test/fixtures/users.yml, keys: ["one",
>   "email",I'mtwo"]

im getting confuse what should i do,pplz give some suggesstions

Comment: You might be getting this error because your users.yml isn't indented properly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html "Each fixture is given a name followed by an indented list of colon-separated key/value pairs. Records are typically separated by a blank line."

Comment: Is your user.yml is properly indent? Please insure that email under one should be 1 indent inside. That means one and 2 should be on 0 indent and email should be on one.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your `user.yml` file has to be fixed:

```
one:
  email: test1@test.com

two:
  email: test2@test.com
```

The error message itself is a good hint about this, "fixture key is not a hash: ... keys: ["one", "email",I'mtwo"]" you can see in the list of keys that there exist the `one` and `email` keys. What you should instead have are only the `one` and `two` keys.